# TOPSY JSON [searchcount] not working except for IE9 in local machine

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

Im working on topsy json **searchcount** but when i run it on local machine, result only appear on safari and IE9. when i put it online, everything not working.

here is the script

```
$.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.json?q=json", function(response) {
  alert(response.response.w);
 });
```

i took the json from http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/wiki/Resources#/searchcount

something wrong my the script?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to append your search with a callback to use JSONP over JSON. Here's what the URL should look like

```
$.getJSON("http://otter.topsy.com/searchcount.json?q=json&callback=?", function(response){
 alert(response.response.w);
});
```

**Edit:** Here's a couple of useful links
http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/wiki/ResponseFormats#Javascript_(JSONP)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in the jsonp response. That might be screwing up IE9?